# Error in names(x) <- value : 'names' attribute [8] must be the same length as the vector [2]

Tags: r

My personal R website went down this weekend and I narrowed it down to the R package `BatchGetSymbols`.

The error occurs when just running a simple command as shown in my code.  Anyone else having this issue, or know how to resolve it?

The error in the console is:

> 'names' attribute [8] must be the same length as the vector [2]

Not sure where to start.

```
library(BatchGetSymbols)
df.SP500 <- GetSP500Stocks()
print(df.SP500)
```

Comment: I suggest you open an issue with the author. https://github.com/msperlin/BatchGetSymbols/issues

Comment: On May 8 2018 [somebody added an extra column](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=List_of_S%26P_500_companies&type=revision&diff=840321235&oldid=838979851) to the [Wikipedia list of SP500 stocks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_S%26P_500_companies).  Perhaps this or some other formatting change broke the `GetSP500Stocks()` web-scraping function

Comment: The strange part about this is that I am not seeing any updates as of late and my site was working just 2 or 3 days ago (not sure exactly when it went down).  I sent the issue to the author.  I will keep everyone posted to see if there was some sort of mass update, or if this issue is exclusive to myself.

Answer (score 1):

I tracked the issue down in the `BatchGetSymbols::GetSP500Stocks` function. The only issue was the `xpath` argument in `html_nodes` - we must get the 2nd table instead of the 1st (`/div/table[2]` not `/div/table[1]`). Until the author has fixed it on his side, you can work around by using the following code:

```
library(BatchGetSymbols)    
my.GetSP500Stocks <- function(){
    my.url <- "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_S%26P_500_companies"
    read_html <- 0
    df.SP500Stocks <- my.url %>% read_html() %>% html_nodes(xpath = "//*[@id=\"mw-content-text\"]/div/table[2]") %>% html_table()
    df.SP500Stocks <- df.SP500Stocks[[1]]
    colnames(df.SP500Stocks) <- c("tickers", "company", "SEC.filings", "GICS.Sector", "GICS.Sub.Industry", "Address", "Date.first.added", "CIK", "Founded")
    return(df.SP500Stocks)
}
my.GetSP500Stocks() %>% as_tibble()
#> # A tibble: 505 x 9
#>    tickers company SEC.filings GICS.Sector GICS.Sub.Indust~ Address
#>    <chr>   <chr>   <chr>       <chr>       <chr>            <chr>  
#>  1 MMM     3M Com~ reports     Industrials Industrial Cong~ St. Pa~
#>  2 ABT     Abbott~ reports     Health Care Health Care Equ~ North ~
#>  3 ABBV    AbbVie~ reports     Health Care Pharmaceuticals  North ~
#>  4 ABMD    ABIOME~ reports     Health Care Health Care Equ~ Danver~
#>  5 ACN     Accent~ reports     Informatio~ IT Consulting &~ Dublin~
#>  6 ATVI    Activi~ reports     Communicat~ Interactive Hom~ Santa ~
#>  7 ADBE    Adobe ~ reports     Informatio~ Application Sof~ San Jo~
#>  8 AMD     Advanc~ reports     Informatio~ Semiconductors   Sunnyv~
#>  9 AAP     Advanc~ reports     Consumer D~ Automotive Reta~ Roanok~
#> 10 AES     AES Co~ reports     Utilities   Independent Pow~ Arling~
#> # ... with 495 more rows, and 3 more variables: Date.first.added <chr>,
#> #   CIK <int>, Founded <chr>
```

Answer (score 0):

How do I update to the author's fixed version?

Also, your patch no longer works - it now says " Error in if (length(p) > 1 & maxp * n != sum(unlist(nrows)) & maxp * n !=  : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed "

Comment: Someone moved the table back up to div 1. LOL. Maybe we should use another source of data, Wikipedia changes a lot.

Comment: Anyways, I made some amendments that I *think* work for now at least. Not sure why I got an error about need for a 10th column but :/

Comment: they also moved hte columns around --;

Comment: my.GetSP500Stocks <- function(){
+     my.url <- "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_S%26P_500_companies"
+     read_html <- 0
+     df.SP500Stocks <- my.url %>% read_html() %>% html_nodes(xpath = "//*[@id=\"mw-content-text\"]/div/table[1]") %>% html_table(fill=TRUE)
+     df.SP500Stocks <- df.SP500Stocks[[1]]
+     colnames(df.SP500Stocks) <- c("company", "tickers", "SEC.filings", "GICS.Sector", "GICS.Sub.Industry", "Address", "Date.first.added", "CIK", "Founded", "Blank")
+     return(df.SP500Stocks)
+ }